# commit folder in the untracked folder

Tags: git

in git large file system, I have untracked some folder, say folder1, say it contains very huge trunks (a lot large of folders) of things... I have previously untracked it to avoid errors (since I even after i just git pull and git push, it would say it has changed and push tons of things online which is complete waste of resources). ok now, I have added something in folder 1 locally, say:

```
folder1/important_update1
```

I want to only commit folder1/important_update1 but nothing else... What should I do?

should i just do:

```
git commmit folder1/important_update1
git push
```

Comment: I would suggest adding things that are in folder1 to git ignore file that you don't want to be tracked. [https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) Please have a look at this for files that are still being tracked after being added to git ignore config file - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: There are too many things in folder1, hundreds.. thousands of folders... I am using git LFS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the file using `git add -f folder1/important_update1` and commit your changes afterwards. In the future your changes to that file will not be ignored.

You could also ignore the contents of folder1 and exclude important_update1 from that using these entries in your `.gitignore`:

```
folder1/*
!folder1/important_update1
```

The first line is important as you can not exclude files if their parent directory has been ignored before (so this wouldn't work if the first line were just `folder1`).

The latter method might be useful if you want to "unignore" all files matching a specific pattern, e.g. use `!folder1/important_update*` to avoid ignoring all files and folders starting with `important_update` within `folder1`.